# GCP Firestore export - filter by field in document

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently struggling with exporting documents from Firestore's collection. In one of my collections there are basically few types of json frames. Difference between them is in "operationType" line at the end of every document.
I'm asking is there any way to export only one type of those documents? I need files with operationType: "TRANSACTION"
If there is no such possibility, is there any way find certains documents by timestamps used there?

Comment: The Firestore API allows you to query to only get those documents. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries If you are having a hard time making those work, edit your question to show where you got stuck. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following: ( This is a Python code)

```
// get the collection
const collections = firestore.collection('collection_name').get()

// get all documents
const documents = shopSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

console.log(documents);

// iterate over the documents and get only those documents which are operationType = Transactions
newDocumentsList = []
for(var i=0; i<documents.length; i++){
    if(documents[i].operationType = 'TRANSACTION'):
         newDocumentsList.add(docuemtns[i])
```